# tikz style border

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{rec} = [rectangle, rounded corners , minimum height=1.5cm,text centered, draw,fill={rgb,255:red,255; green,255; blue,225}]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

\node (start) [rec] {\textbf{M3 Cortex MCU \\STM32F103}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So I am trying to create this style like on below but I can not add shadow,border like this nor make text to be like this.Any suggestion :(
[image: 2]

Comment: `\sffamily` will make the font sans serif, which is one of your issues.

Comment: To get multiple lines, you can stack the text in the node: `\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}` and then: `\node (start) [rec] {\sffamily\textbf{\Centerstack{M3 Cortex MCU \\STM32F103}}};
`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Okay thanks I fixed that and set width but I still can not figure out how to make this boreder and this shade.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes do you know any tutorial or some kind of post,example that could help me

Answer (score 1):

I know very little about `tikz`.  But I know if you search this site, you can often solve your problem by finding similar examples.  Modification from the OP's code involve border, shadow, stacking text in the node, `inner sep`, `\sffamily`, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\newlength{\borderwidth}
\setlength{\borderwidth}{2mm}
\tikzstyle{rec} = [rectangle, rounded corners , minimum height=1.5cm,
  text centered, border = blue!70!red, inner sep=10pt,
  blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5},
  draw,fill={rgb,255:red,255; green,255; blue,225}]

\tikzset{
border/.style = {
    postaction = {clip, postaction = {draw = #1, solid, 
    line width = \borderwidth, path fading=west, 
    postaction={draw, path fading = north}},
    }
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node (start) [rec] {\sffamily\bfseries
  \Centerstack{M3 Cortex MCU \\STM32F103}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this box is not to be placed inside a `tikzpicture`, it can be built with a `tcbox` from `tcolorbox`.

More or less:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\newtcbox{nicebox}[1][]{%
    enhanced, notitle, boxrule=2mm, fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
    frame style={upper left=red!70!blue!50!white, 
    upper right=red!70!blue!40!white,
    lower left=red!60!blue!40!white,
    lower right=red!50!blue!30!white},
    drop fuzzy shadow,
    colback={rgb,255:red,255; green,255; blue,225},
    tikznode,
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\nicebox{M3 Cortex MCU\\STM32F103}

\end{document}
```

[image]